# VS Load Test with Staging/Development setup following 301 Redirect

Tags: load-testing, azure-pipelines

I currently have a setup with Azure Pipelines that deploy to a staging environment, then swaps to the development environment.

I also have a load test that executes to validate performance.

The problem is, if "staging" is currently active, then I am hit with 301 redirects, and the load test fails.

If "development" is enabled, then all runs well for the duration of the tests.

Base URL is "https:.azurewebsites.com/api/..."
Staging URL is "https:.azurewebsites.com/api/..."

Now when my CI/CD pipeline runs, staging becomes base, and the base becomes staging, as that is how the "Swap" functionality works in the Azure Pipeline. The URL stays the same (public facing), however, behind the scenes, a redirect apparently is happening. This is what is causing the 301 redirects within my load test. If I run the CI/CD pipeline twice in a row, then all works fine. Or, I can just run "swap" twice, but that defeats the purpose, plus I lose the quick rollback functionality.

So depending on which stage of the ping pong swap I am in, the load test will pass or fail.

How do I enable follow redirects within the load test so that I don't have to run the CI/CD pipeline twice, just to pass the load test?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain the initial and redirected URLs in both cases. Also there is just too little detail in the question to even guess what is happening.

Comment: Visual Studio's web tests normally process redirects correctly. Have you disabled the `Follow redirects` property of the request? I do not understand what you describe in your test. Can you copy the relevant requests into the question? The `.webtest` file is just XML, but it can be huge so only copy the interesting parts. (Please do not include screenshots of Visual Studio.)